# C++ decltype in static_assert

Tags: c++

```
constexpr uint8_t count = 50;

static_assert(std::is_same_v<uint8_t, decltype(count)>, "fail");
```

result: "fail"

Why not that type?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `static_assert(std::is_same_v<const uint8_t, decltype(count)>, "fail");` instead? Note the `const uint8_t`

Answer (score 6):

This is because `decltype(count)` is `const uint8_t`

Answer (score 4):

`constexpr` implies `const`, so the type of `count` is actually `const uint8_t`.

So this will compile:

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<const uint8_t, decltype(count)>, "fail");
```

See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/b5QirY).

Answer (score 2):

You can also *decay* the type to its simplest form, getting rid of all the `const` and stuff:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>

int main() {
    constexpr uint8_t count = 50;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<uint8_t, std::decay_t<decltype(count)>>, "fail");
    // more code...
}
```